# how to view result of php script on android text view

Tags: php, android, retrofit2

I want to get the result of a PHP script to display on Android Textview using retrofit I was able to send data in an edit text to the database doing something like this

This is for the post method

```
InstituteService instituteService = ApiClient.getApiClient(getApplicationContext()).create(InstituteService.class);
            Call<ServiceResponse> calRegStudent = instituteService.UploadStudentsRecord(Surname,Firstname,Othername,Address,Age,Sex,Parentemail,Sclass,Regno,Tagno,Rollcallno,L_Finger1,L_Finger2,R_Finger1,R_Finger2,District_code,Zone_code,School_code);
            calRegStudent.enqueue(new Callback<ServiceResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ServiceResponse> call, Response<ServiceResponse> response) {
                    if(response.body() != null)
                    {
                        ServiceResponse rr= response.body();
                        if(rr.getStatus().contentEquals("1"))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data Submit Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            ClearEditTextAfterDoneTask();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        }
```

The code for the get Method

```
InstituteService instituteService = ApiClient.getApiClient(getApplicationContext()).create(InstituteService.class);
                    Call<ServiceResponse> calRegStudent = instituteService.StudentGetRecord(Parentemail);
                    calRegStudent.enqueue(new Callback<ServiceResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<ServiceResponse> call, Response<ServiceResponse> response) {
                            if(response.body() != null)
                            {
                                ServiceResponse rr= response.body();
                                if(rr.getStatus().contentEquals("1"))
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    ClearEditTextAfterDoneTask();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                }
```

I can only send the field needed to make the query but I have no idea how to display the result.

This the PHP script of the get method I am working on

```
<?php

//Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
//Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$parentemail=htmlspecialchars( $_GET["parentemail"]);
$sql = "SELECT surname,firstname,othername,rollcallno FROM studentTable WHERE parentemail='$parentemail';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo(json_encode(array('Message'=>"New record created successfully",'Status'=>1)));
    //echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo(json_encode(array('Message'=>mysql_error($conn),'Status'=>0)));
    //echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

This is the InstituteService

```
    package com.ainakay.studentapp;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Header;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface InstituteService {
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("insertin.php")
    Call<ServiceResponse> UploadStudentsRecord(@Field("surname") String surname,@Field("firstname") String firstname,
                                       @Field("othername") String othername,@Field("address") String address,
                                       @Field("age") String age,@Field("sex") String sex,@Field("parentemail") String parentemail,
                                       @Field("sclass") String sclass,@Field("regno") String regno,
                                       @Field("tagno") String tagno,@Field("rollcallno") String rollcallno,
                                       @Field("l_Finger1") String l_Finger1,@Field("l_Finger2") String l_Finger2,
                                       @Field("r_Finger1") String r_Finger1,@Field("r_Finger2") String r_Finger2,
                                       @Field("district_code") String district_code,@Field("zone_code") String zone_code,@Field("school_code") String school_code);
@FormUrlEncoded
    @GET("parentgetstudent.php")
    Call<ServiceResponse> StudentGetRecord(@Field("parentemail")String parentemail);


}
```

Please am fairly new to android development will appreciate any sort of help

Comment: What you need is writing rr.getMessage() in a TextView?

Comment: what you want to exactly ?

Comment: @MehulTank I want the names which are the result of the of the SQL query in the PHP script to show as the text of a textview in a layout

Comment: Please explain better i don't know how to do that @JaviMollá

Comment: you need column name ?

Comment: I'm sorry but your code makes no sense: Surname,Firstname,Othername,Address are input parameters of the UploadStudentsRecord function, not output parameters. The PHP script returns only a message reporting if there was an error with sql or saying that a new record was created but there is no creation, only a select executed twice. Focus on doing first the PHP part and then move on to the Android integration

Comment: @JaviMollá I have now shown my code for the get method. Please help me with how the PHP script  for the get method should look like.

Comment: @Mehul the text in those column is what i want to display on Textview

Comment: After you do execute the `SELECT` query, you need to fetch the results! You can use `mysqli_fetch_array()` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`. Check these examples for some idea: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran i have used the mysqli_fetch_array() to fetch result. How can i now display on Textview in layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for the server part, you have to return all the fields that you need to show in Android:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if ($result) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo(json_encode(array(
      'Message' => "OK",
      'Status' => 1,
      'Surname' => $row['surname'], 
      'Firstname' => $row['firstname'], 
      'Othername' => $row['othername']
      // Rest of the fields
    )));
} else {
    echo(json_encode(array('Message' => mysql_error($conn), 'Status' => 0)));
}
```

And for the client side:

```
ServiceResponse rr = response.body();
if (rr.getStatus().contentEquals("1"))
{
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    txtSurname.setText(rr.getSurname());
    txtFirstname.setText(rr.getFirstname());
    // Rest of the fields
}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```